# Select objects based on an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a list of `Movie`s and a movie has an array of genres. Most movies have only one genre, but some of them have two, like `"Drama"` and `"Comedy"`. I need to select all movies that match one or more category. For example, I want a query to select movies that are `"Drama"` or `"Comedy"`. I did this

```
@movies.select { |mov| mov.genres.include? ['Drama', 'Comedy'] }
```

But this select seems to be exclusive: it searches for movies that are both `"Drama"` and `"Comedy"`. Is there a way to do that in one line or should I iterate over all genres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
query = %w[Drama Comedy]; @movies.reject{|e| (e.genres & query).empty?}
```